# Ruby Compare 2 Arrays of Hashes with Sets of Keys

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

So I have 2 arrays of hashes, which look something like this:

```
arr1 = [{:tag=>"ABC_0001", :bocount=>100, :bocreated=>"2017-02-24T14:57:39.549-05:00"},{:tag=>"ABC_0002", :bocount=>50, :bocreated=>"2017-02-24T14:57:41.156-05:00"},{:tag=>"ABC_0003", :bocount=>10, :bocreated=>"2017-02-24T14:57:42.903-05:00"},{:tag=>"ABC_0004", :bocount=>12, :bocreated=>"2017-02-24T14:57:44.156-05:00"}]

arr2 = [{:tag=>"ABC_0001", :bocount=>100, :bocreated=>"2017-01-24T14:57:39.549-05:00"},{:tag=>"ABC_0003", :bocount=>10, :bocreated=>"2017-01-24T14:57:42.903-05:00"},{:tag=>"ABC_0004", :bocount=>12, :bocreated=>"2017-01-24T14:57:44.156-05:00"},{:tag=>"ABC_0005", :bocount=>75, :bocreated=>"2017-01-24T14:57:41.156-05:00"}]
```

What I need to do, is remove the bocreated hashes from these arrays, entirely.  I need to make a copy of each array (got that), and then in the new array, remove all bocreated hashes.

I have looked everywhere, but can't seem to find this exactly.  Mostly about removing certain values.

I tried this:

```
oi_newset.each do |h|
    h.delete("#{h[:bocreated]}")
end
```

but when I output the array, those hashes are still there.

If anyone can help, that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: The header seems completely unrelated to the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
oi_newset.each do |h|
  h.delete(:bocreated)
end
```

You need to delete the key.

Comment: Thanks! That was perfect. I'm just a moron with the wrong syntax, over here.

Comment: Cheers! Glad I could help.